# jQuery change nearest span display style on select option changed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this block:

```
<div class="user-select-dropdown">
    <span class="filter-header">User:</span>
    <span class="remove-option">✖</span>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="filter.UserId" ng-change="filterModel(filter)" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in usersList">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Select user...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And my span with `X` is the button that reset `select` option, but when `select` is without any options, my remove-option is `display: none;`, and I need to show it when I change to any option.
I have this css:

```
.remove-option {
    display: none;
    bottom: 14%;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 7%;
    z-index: 99999;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.user-select-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

And this jquery:

```
$(".remove-option").click(function () {
    $(this).next("select").val($("select option:first").val());
});

$(".form-control").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() >= 0)
        $(this).next(".remove-option").css("display: block");
    else
        $(this).next(".remove-option").css("display: none");
});
```

`.form-control` is bootstrap class.

The problem is that `$(this).next(".remove-option").css(...)` not working, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `$(this).prev(".remove-option")` - the span is the previous sibling so use `.prev()` not `.next()`

Comment: `ng-model` Are you using Angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your html, the span is the previous sibling of the form-control element so use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev)

```
$(".form-control").change(function () {
    $(this).next(".remove-option").toggle($(this).val() >= 0);
});
```

You can also use .toggle() to change the display in a single line as given above

---

Since it looks like you are using angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.usersList = [{
    Id: 1,
    Name: '1'
  }, {
    Id: 2,
    Name: '2'
  }, {
    Id: 3,
    Name: '3'
  }, {
    Id: 4,
    Name: '4'
  }];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <div class="user-select-dropdown">
    <span class="filter-header">User:</span>
    <span class="remove-option" ng-show="filter.UserId > 0">✖</span>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="filter.UserId" ng-change="filterModel(filter)" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in usersList">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select user...</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `remove-option` element is before your `form-control`, you have to use `prev` and not `next`.

```
$(".form-control").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() >= 0)
        $(this).prev(".remove-option").css("display: block");
    else
        $(this).prev(".remove-option").css("display: none");
});
```